# Display Days In Output: ActionScript 3.0

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I am having a little trouble with displaying the days of the week in my output label. So far I got my output label to say day1, day2, day3, and so on. I'm not sure how to make it say Sunday, Monday, Tuesday, etc. 
This is how my code is so far with just the words day1, day2, day3, etc. I would really appreciate it, if you could help me make it say the words of the days of the week.

```
function displayTemperatures(e:MouseEvent):void
{
    lblOutput.text = "";
    var i:int = 1
    for(var x=0; x < temperatures.length; x++)
{
    lblOutput.text += "Day " + i++ + ":  " + temperatures[x] + "\r";
}
}
```

Temperatures is a global variable that is classifies as an Array: new Array()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

all you need is another array . 
e.g  `var days:Array = ["sunday","monday",...];`

`lblOutput.text += days[i] ..."